# How to redirect to a page with 2 parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I'm trying to redirect 2 parameters:

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="h1" NavigateUrl='OrderFromSupplies.aspx?Gender=<%#Eval("Gender") %>&<%#Eval("Name")%>'><%#Eval("Name") %></asp:HyperLink><br/>
```

And that is the url I get:

http://localhost:31397/user/admin/OrderFromSupplies.aspx?Gender=%3C%#Eval(%22Gender%22)%20%%3E&%3C%#Eval(%22Name%22)%%3E
How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

You have to at least separate/isolate the code `Eval()` from the markup.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" id="h1" 
    NavigateUrl='OrderFromSupplies.aspx?Gender=' +
        <%#Eval("Gender")%>
        + '&' +
        <%#Eval("Name")%>>
            <%#Eval("Name")%>
</asp:HyperLink>
```